# Custom choices on form with data_class

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have created a `FormType` that get's a `data_class` set in the defaults in the `configureOptions` class. It looks a bit like this

```
<?php
namespace tzfrs\AppBundle\Form\Type;

use tzfrs\AppBundle\Model\Car;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

/**
 * Class CarType
 * @package tzfrs\AppBundle\Form\Type
 */
class CarType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('specification', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => [1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3]
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Car::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

When I now create the form like this

`$carForm = $this->createForm(CarType::class, $car);`

and want to use it I get the following error:

> The value of type "object" cannot be converted to a valid array key.

I think the reason for this, is because my `Car` class has a property `specification` with getters/setters and therefore returns a `Specification` object. However, my `Specification` object has a `__toString()` method.

`Car.php`

```
/**
* @var Specification
*/
protected $specification;

public function getSpecification(): Specification
{
    return $this->specification;
}

public function setSpecification(Specification $specification): Car
{
    $this->specification = $specfification;
    return $this;
}
```

`Specification.php`

```
/**
 * Returns a string implementation of the current class
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function __toString(): string
{
    return sprintf(
        'HP: %s,CCM: %s',
        $this->getHorsePower(),
        $this->getCapacity()
    );
}
```

How would I achieve overriding my choices for a form field which uses a custom Model? I can't use the `EntityType` because it's not a Doctrine Model.

When I build my form like this

`$carForm = $this->createForm(Car::class);`

then it works, but I need the `Car` object inside the Form, because of another field I'm adding in the `buildForm` method

Comment: Use [`DataTransformers`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html) on the `specification`-field. Though it might be *cleaner* to extract the specification to it's own type and use data transformers there.

Comment: Hey. I think I solved the issue. Since I didn't want to use a single `specification` but a list of `specifications` where the user can choose, it was the wrong way to simply try to use the underlying data. I set `mapped` to `false`.. So simple, no idea why I didn't thought about this earlier